# What's the difference between the `&` and `&&` in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

What's the difference between the `&` and `&&` in Vue.js?

I test the:

```
<span
  v-if="1 > 0 & 2 > 1"
>
  span
</span>
```

and

```
<span
  v-if="1 > 0 && 2 > 1"
>
  span
</span>
```

both the text `span` will show.

So is there some difference between them in Vue.js?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vue in particular, they're two different javascript operators.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They have the same type of logic. 0101 & 1010 = 0000. However && will not valuate the second one if the first on is false, it will always consider the second one true..

try this

```
<span
  v-if="1 > 3 && 2 > 3"
>
  span
</span>
```